# How to display results in separate columns in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for a number theory proof but I have very little experience in writing code.

What i want to do is display all the results of the formula:

```
                             Answer = sqrt [4*n]
```

where;
n = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...50

But I want to display the results in 2 groups of columns, i.e.,

- I want the 1st column to be the 1st half of n. So as there are 50 iterations, the 1st column will contain the numbers 0 --> 25.
- The 2nd column should display the first 25 Answers from the equation.
- The 3rd column has the second half of n. i.e., The numbers 26-->50
- The 4th column should display the results from the last 25 values of n.

An example of what I'm trying to display is below*:
*(ignore the dots in the below example, they are only there for display purposes only)

n:............Answer:............n:...........Answer:

So far i have the code working but I just can't figure out how to split and display the n-values and Answer-values as I have shown above.
All I can manage to do is display the values in only 2 columns as follows:

n:...........Answer:

This is what I've got so far:

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath> //preprocesser directives

    using namespace std; //avoids having to use std:: with cout/cin


    int main (int argc, char* argv[])


    {
        int n;
        float Ans;

        cout << setw(4) << "n:" <<  "\t\t" << setw(4) << "Answer:" << "\n" << endl;



    for (int n = 0; n<=50; n++)
    {
    Ans = sqrt ((4)*(n));   

    cout  << setw(4) << n <<  "\t\t" << setprecision(4) << setw(4) << Ans << endl;

    }    

    cout << "\n\nPress enter to end" << endl;

    cin.get(); 

    }
```

I really have no idea how to split it into 4 separate columns, but I know the \t function must have something to do with it!??

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: You can separate the print and calculation loops. Have an array of your data first, then pull the elements you want to print out in the print loop

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using an array, as I really have no idea on how to do that! Im not a programmer at all, im only a lowly mathematician! :)

Comment: FYI, instead of using the global `namespace std`, you can specifically call out the ones you are using: `using std::cout; using std::cin;`.

Comment: @SwimBikeRun: Why should he use an array instead of std::vector for such a high-level task?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I agree. I chose arrays because I suck at c++, and arrays get the job done. Care to modify my version to vectors so I can see what it looks like?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered! they all worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for loop to:

```
for (int n = 1; n<=25; n++)
{   
    Ans = sqrt ((4)*(n));   
    cout  << setw(4) << n <<  "\t\t" << setprecision(4) << setw(4) << Ans << "\t\t";
    Ans = sqrt ((4)*(n + 25));   
    cout  << setw(4) << n + 25 <<  "\t\t" << setprecision(4) << setw(4) << Ans << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This one was perfect for my needs!

Answer (score 0):

Loop from 1 to 25 and in the loop body, calculate two results: the one for n and the one for n + 25.

Here is a very simple compilable and runnable example showing you the basic idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    for (int n = 1; n <= 25; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << n << "\t" << sqrt(n) << "\t"
            << (n + 25) << "\t" << sqrt(n + 25) << "\n";
    }
}
```

This may already be sufficient for your needs. However, notice that I've used tabulators. That's easily written but makes correct output depend on tab size, i.e. you may get incorrectly aligned columns on some displays or editors.

One solution for this problem would be to create HTML output, use the `<table>` element and let a web browser take care of displaying an actual table:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "<table>\n"; // and other HTML stuff
    for (int n = 1; n <= 25; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << "<tr>";
        std::cout << "<td>" << n << "</td><td>" << sqrt(n) << "</td><td>"
            << (n + 25) << "</td><td>" << sqrt(n + 25);
        std::cout << "</tr>\n";
    }
    std::cout << "</table>\n";
}
```

If you are on Windows, then compile this into, say, output.exe, and call it as follows to create an HTML file:

```
output.exe >output.html
```

If you want pure text output, things get harder. You'd have to calculate all results in advance, store them in a `std::vector`, convert each of them to `std::string`s, look at the strings' sizes, pick the longest, *then* output all items with appropriate padding spaces. In fact, you'd have to learn a lot of new things for that, which would probably result in one or two additional, more specific questions on Stack Overflow.

**Edit:** You are using `setw(4)`. Actually, that's another reasonable solution to the problem if you are happy with a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

This solution solves your problem and has the advantage of solving similar problems where you have to output (x,y) pairs to a four column table. You aren't locked into inputs increasing 1,2,3 etc.

Add this to top of file, with other includes

```
#include <vector>
```

Add this to body

```
cout << setw(4) << "n:" <<  "\t\t" << setw(4) << "Answer:" << "\n" << endl;

std::vector<double> inputs;
std::vector<double> answers;

for (int n = 0; n<=50; n++){
    inputs.push_back(n);  
    inputs.push_back(sqrt(4*n));
}
for (int n = 1; n<=25; n++){
    cout  << setw(4) << Inputs[n] <<  "\t\t" << setprecision(4) << setw(4) << Answers[n] << "\t\t" << setw(4) << Inputs[n+25] <<  "\t\t" << setprecision(4) << setw(4) << Answers[n+25] << endl;
}
```

Comment: This should be a lower-case `double`, and it should use `std::vector`. We're not in Java here :) So, for example, `std::vector<double> inputs;`. Then you just add elements as you go: `inputs.push_back(n); answers.push_back(sqrt(4 * n))`. Element access has the same syntax as arrays: `inputs[n]`.

Comment: Cool thanks. Do you have to include something for std::vector to work?

Comment: `#include <vector>` - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector or *any* introductory material on the C++ standard library.